# How to get the default currency and percentage symbol

Tags: jquery, globalization

How to get the default currency and percentage symbol of particular culture using Globalize 1.0 file and how to change the symbol dynamically.

Please help me to find the solution...

Thanks

Comment: The percentage symbol is same for any kind of culture, No?

Comment: Back or Forth i think. 50% or %50.

Comment: Can you show us your code so far?

Comment: But I'd look at the [jQuery Globalize number-module docs](https://github.com/jquery/globalize#number-module) and the [jQuery Globalize currency-module docs](https://github.com/jquery/globalize#currency-module)